# How to take derivative of algebraic function with respect to s

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am reading some books and papers on operational calculus (which is quite similar to Laplace transform) and am unable to understand some of the workings/derivations. So I guess I need to understand the basics: If we have a function $y(t)$ that has already been transformed to the operational domain $Y(s)$, then how do I go about differentiating Y(s) with respect to $s$?

Suppose I have the following algebraic equation

$s^5 Y(s) = s y(0) + s^2 y'(0) + s^3y''(0)$

What is $\dfrac{d}{ds}$? How about $\dfrac{d^2}{ds^2}$?

(Note that I have invented the equation above. I just need to know how to take the derivative with respect to $s$ for terms containing both $s$ and $y^i(0)$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y(0), y'(0)$ and $y''(0)$ are all constants, the right hand side is simply a cubic polynomial in $s$ and is easy to differentiate.

On the left, you have the function $$F(s)=s^5\cdot Y(s)$$

which you can differentiate using the product rule, i.e.

$$\frac{dF}{ds} = \frac{d}{ds}(s^5)\cdot Y(s) + s^5\frac{d}{ds}Y(s)$$

which simplifies to $$5s^4Y(s) + s^5 Y'(s)$$

where $Y'$ denotes $$\frac{dY}{ds}$$

Comment: Thanks twice. One for the answer and one for the prompt response.